# IDE, Framework, code manager tool, thing that supports Java and C++ in one Project

Tags: java, c++, ide

I have inherited someone else's code.  He used CMake to build the fragments for C++ and the fragments for Java/Android.  I cannot believe that he would have used Notepad and Windows Explorer to manage his package/class structure and implementation.  Is there a code manager tool or IDE that allows you to put your Java code in one package and your C++ in another package?  The CMake scripts would build the projects separately, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake is just a build tool.

You can use any IDE you like to write the code and then use a different tool to build it.

Eclipse supports both Java and C++, but I wouldn't recommend it for either.

Comment: You could use `emacs`

Comment: You are correct.  If the project is Android or Java, you can add C++ nature to the project by right-clicking your project >> New >> Other >> C/C++ >> Convert to a C/C++ Project.  That works!  Thanks.